# Change liferay resource label

Tags: spring-mvc, liferay, workflow, portlet

i create a new liferay asset resource successfully, but i can't set a custom label to my new resource.

[Workflow Control Panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2CaE.jpg)

As you can see in the attached image, i have a resource labeled as "model.resource.com.it.portlet.gestionincidencias.model.Incidencia".

I want to change the label "model.resource.com.it.portlet.gestionincidencias.model.Incidencia" and set only the name of my model class "Incidencia"

Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a global language hook which declare language properties and add you key inside.

In liferay-hook.xml:

```
<language-properties>content/Language.properties</language-properties>
```

And in your Language.properties file:

```
model.resource.com.it.portlet.gestionincidencias.model.Incidencia=Incendia
```